# Getting "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /myenv/include/python3.6m/Python-ast.h: no such file or directory" while docker-compose build

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose

So I am pretty new to docker and django. Unfortunately while running the below command on my linux machine which i am connected using my physical windows machine using putty:

```
docker-compose build
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /myenv/include/python3.6m/Python-ast.h: no such file or directory
```

'myenv' is the environment I have created inside my folder.

I am getting a container started on port 9000. The app doesn't have anything yet just a simple project so i just expect to see the 'congratulations' screen. I don't know where I am going wrong. My final goal would be to run the docker url in my windows browser and see the screen of docker container.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
     web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
        ports:
            - 202.179.92.106:8000:9000
```

the IP: `202.179.92.106` is my public IP. I did the above binding so as to access the docker container from my windows machine. Would request additional inputs for the port binding as well if correct/incorrect.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.9

RUN mkdir djangotest

WORKDIR djangotest

ADD . /djangotest

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Please help me out peeps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a virtual environment in your normal development tree, you can't copy it into a Docker image.  You can exclude this from the build sequence by mentioning it in a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

```
# .dockerignore
myenv
```

Within the Dockerfile, the `RUN pip install` line will install your application's dependencies into the Docker image, so you should have a complete self-contained image.

Comment: OMG! thanks a ton! silly me now it got build.

Comment: ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint djangotest_web_1 (8b3e572fee4bef402e0c9a796dbaa73ee4a6dfb4affdf7cb3e73001af9ca9283): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 202.179.92.106:8000: bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: getting the above error while running docker-compose up, any idea?